# Нарисовать визуальную сетку css/js

Tags: css3, javascript, html, css, html5

Нужно внутри корневго div нарисовать сетку (или поставить точки в углы сетки), причем к размерам ячеек я должен иметь доступ через js (т.е. картинка с сетрой на background не подходит)
Сделал при помощи абсолютного позиционирования блоков т.е. куча div с координатами, сгенерированными через js.
Решение не нравится, т.к. корневой div может быть огромной высоты, и не очень хочется в него генерировать сотни элементов.

Есть идеи?

[Пример сетки](http://s3.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2013/07/66d7c344625ae29eb1ab9127912d0480.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поставьте в фон `canvas` и нарисуйте сетку на нём: http://jsfiddle.net/XktVp/

Answer (score 0):

Можно увеличивать размер сетки и через background просто увеличивая масштаб изображения.

Comment: Картинка размоется