# Как нарисовать динамическую сетку в background для div?

Tags: javascript, css

Стоит задача: нарисовать сетку вроде координатной как на графиках (или миллиметровой бумаге, например) в фоне контейнера вроде [этой](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-bBa4jUY6nc0/U5zvbFtXuhI/AAAAAAAADPo/v9OsLiCJ7CE/s320/WW05-pentwords.png).
Есть `div`, размер его в `px` изначально неизвестен, но известно, что, предположим, ширина 30% от ширины окна (не экрана, т.е. при изменении размеров окна пользователем ширина `div` также меняется). Его `background` должен содержать сетку из заранее известного количества ячеек `Х`. `Div` может растягиваться, сжиматься, сетка должна при этом меняться пропорционально, и количество ячеек должно оставаться равным `Х`.
Фоновый рисунок - т.к. в этом `div` поверх сетки будет располагаться контент.

[Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/239427/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83-css-js) есть вариант решения через `canvas`, однако там строго задается шаг сетки, поэтому такой вариант не подходит.

[Попробовал высчитывать ширину ячеек](http://jsfiddle.net/XktVp/87/) на основе ширины `div`.
Однако как решить проблему изменения размера div? Фон при этом должен пропорционально меняться, количество ячеек оставаться тем же, а ширина-высота ячеек, соответственно, уже будет другой.

Comment: А таблицей не хотите сделать? Т.е. использовать ее как подложку.

Comment: @AleksanderK. интересный вариант. а как ее можно сделать подложкой?

Comment: Приложил пример.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант с использованием таблицы:

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.graph {
    width: 30%;
    height: 30%;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

.graph-grid {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-spacing: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

.graph-grid td {
    border-left: 1px solid #eee;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="graph">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
    
    <table class="graph-grid">
        <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr> 
        <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr> 
        <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr> 
    </table>
</div>
```